# Undefined Method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined

I am new to Ruby on Rails and im stuck on something so simple but I just cant figure it out.

I scaffolded a Video model, controller and view and then created a Welcome controller for the home page.

I manually created an index.html.erb file in the welcome view folder and proceeded to route the home page to Welcome#index. All working fine for now.

Thing is when I define a method in the **welcome_controller** like this

```
def foo
   puts 'Hello'
end
```

and I call it in the **welcome/index.html** file like this

```
<%= foo %>
```

I get the following error: undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<#:0x39675d8>

Answer (score 1):

Controller actions aren't view helpers, you'll want to put `foo` in either `application_helper.rb` or `welcome_helper.rb` to use it like you are and change it to *remove the `puts`*, like this:

```
def foo
  'Hello'
end
```

This will insert `Hello` into your view (which is what I think you were expecting)

Based on your comments below, you should probably be using a `scope` in your model...

```
scope :highlighted -> { (where(highlight: true) }
```

... to return highlighted records from your controller...

```
@highlighted = Videos.highlighted
```

... and then iterate over @highlighted in your view...

```
<% @highlighted.each do |video| %>
<%= ...do something with video here... %>
<% end %>
```

please read more about all this here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html

and specificially for scopes here...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: What im trying to do is call this method 

   `module WelcomeHelper
      def search_highlight
        @highlighted = Videos.where(highlight: true)
        puts @highlighted
      end
    end`

but now I am getting an uninitialized constant error. I tried with just outputing "hello" and the undefined methor error went away but the "hello" isnt outputting on screen.

Comment: don't use `puts`... you want the method to return a string (or another object), not send it to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call arbitrary "things" in the controller.

What's exposed in the controller are its instance variables, e.g., `@foo`.

If you *really* want to call a method that uses `puts`, put it in a helper, e.g., `welcome_helper.rb` (or whatever the convention would be).

Note, however, that this won't do what you appear to believe it will, namely, put a "Hello" on the web page. You're basically writing directly to the console, not even the log file.

What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What im trying to do is call this method 

   `module WelcomeHelper
      def search_highlight
        @highlighted = Videos.where(highlight: true)
        puts @highlighted
      end
    end`

but now I am getting an uninitialized constant error. I tried with just outputing "hello" and the undefined methor error went away but the "hello" isnt outputting on screen.

Comment: @user3099920 Because `puts` has nothing to do with rendering HTML, as I already said. Helpers are for returning HTML strings. You'd iterate over the videos and return a string of HTML for the collection. I *wouldn't*, I'd use a partial.